# Using joblib to dump a scikit-learn model on x86 then read on z/OS passes in Decision Tree but fails on a GradientBoostingRegressor

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, x86, zos

I have made some small tweaks into NumpyArrayWrapper in numpy_pickle.py to allow a decision tree model to be successfully loaded onto scikit-learn running on z/OS. The change boils down to checking if byte-order is correct and if not call array.byteswap(). However when trying to load a GradientBoostingRegressor model it fails before even reaching the byteswap fix.

The error is coming from this line https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.18.1/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx#L644 and it is because of the following condition `node_ndarray.dtype != NODE_DTYPE`. The reason This is happening because the Gradient Boost Regressor hits the following line of code while Decision Tree does not https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.18.1/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py#L105

I was wondering if anyone knows if there is something different I should be doing because the Dtypes for the DT model seem to be fine when loading on z/OS however they are not for the GBR model. This appears to be coming from the model.fit method because when removing that call I can successfully load the pkl file on z/OS.

Code for training the Gradiant Boosting Model

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris.data, iris.target, test_size=0.2)

gbr = GradientBoostingRegressor(max_depth=3)
model = Pipeline([('Gbr', gbr)])

model.fit(X_train, y_train)


from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(model, 'GBTmodelx86.pkl')
```

Code for training the Decision Tree model

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

dataset = datasets.load_iris()

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(dataset.data, dataset.target)

from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(model, 'DTmodelX86.pkl')
```

Code for loading each model

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
model = joblib.load('DTmodelX86.pkl')
```

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
model = joblib.load('GBTmodelx86.pkl')
```

Comment: Have you tried [asking the vendor](https://forum.rocketsoftware.com/c/rocket-z-os-open-source-languages-tools/python)?

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked 4 yrs ago but I think it still might be worth having an explanation.
When you create an object and export it to a model, the format is not compatible. If you’re going to deploy the model to z/OS you’ll need some utilities to export the model.

You can see here:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/wml-for-zos/2.1.0.3?topic=zos-importing-spark-scikit-learn-xgboost-models

Or in a more modern version:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/wml-for-zos/2.4.0?topic=wmlz-importing-models-from-file

These are if you’re using Machine Learning for z/OS engines.

If you’re just running Python standalone on a mainframe, you’ll need to install the IBM Python AI Toolkit for z/OS:
https://ibm-z-oss-oda.github.io/python_ai_toolkit_zos/

Then, you’ll need to export the model in a compatible format like PMML instead of pkl.

Hope it helps.